# Magento 2 Reorder

Tags: frontend, store-view

How to add image for reorder block in sidebar.phtml?

Here i have tried lot of code from examples so please give some ideas to add that reorder details with images.

Comment: Do you mean "Recently Ordered" block?

Comment: Recently ordered product views. It showing only checkbox and that products names only. I need that product images also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the below file to your custom module, to modify the functionality you need to use plugin:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/CustomerData/LastOrderedItems.php

Update the function **getItems** in your vendor folder for now, later you can manage according to your requirement. The function will look like below after update

```
protected function getItems()
{
    $items = [];
    $order = $this->getLastOrder();
    $limit = self::SIDEBAR_ORDER_LIMIT;

    if ($order) {
        $website = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item */
        foreach ($order->getParentItemsRandomCollection($limit) as $item) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            try {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById(
                    $item->getProductId(),
                    false,
                    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                );
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $noEntityException) {
                $this->logger->critical($noEntityException);
                continue;
            }
            if (isset($product) && in_array($website, $product->getWebsiteIds())) {
                $url = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility() ? $product->getProductUrl() : null;
                $items[] = [
                    'id' => $item->getId(),
                    'name' => $item->getName(),
                    'url' => $url,
                    'thumbnail' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$product->getThumbnail(),
                    'is_saleable' => $this->isItemAvailableForReorder($item),
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Also copy the following file to your respective theme;

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml

and add the below line

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: thumbnail}" class="product-image"/>
```

where you want to place the image. Now update the css accordingly.